# CURLOPT_POST vs CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST

Tags: php, curl

I am using the [Email on Acid API](https://api.emailonacid.com/docs/v4).

While sending `POST` requests to the endpoint `http://sandbox.emailonacid.com/v4/GetClientList` through PHP Curl, I tried the following alternatives :

1. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST")`
2. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

The first option works, but the second option returns an HTTP 400 Bad Request.

Can anyone explain the behavior?

Comment: switch on CURLOPT_VERBOSE as well and compare the sent requests and it might be what you need to figure out why. Note that for most normal POST requests you also send a request-body that you don't mention here...

Comment: I also would want to know.

Answer (score 10):

By default [CURLOPT_POST](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POST.html) will perform a regular POST request using a `Content-Type` header of **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** which is typically the kind used when submitting HTML forms.

---

The API you're consuming has restricted `Accept` headers for `application/json` or `application/xml` depending on whether your sending a JSON or XML payload.

You can override the default `Content-Type` for a regular POST header using:

```
$headers = ['Content-Type: application/json'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Answer (score 3):

During some debugging on one of my projects I found that using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

without providing a payload

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
```

will result in Curl interpreting the call as being a GET call. Which for most api's that expect POST calls will return a 400 http code (Bad request).

If you use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST")
```

you actively set the request type to the value POST and curl will not interpret it as being a GET.